# Correct method of deploying Laravel 8 Application through cPanel

Tags: laravel, git, cpanel, web-deployment

I designed a Laravel 8 app and successfully deployed it via cPanel. What I did was create a git repo in my cPanel. Connected that repo to my local app folder. Pushed the repo from my laptop and deployed it via git's post-receive hook to the `public_html` folder.

Now what I request you seniors to tell me, is what is the best practice of deploying the Laravel project.

a) should I deploy directly to my `public_html` folder via git repo (as I have done) or

b) should I deploy it to another folder and create a symlink pointing to `public_html` folder.

After deploying, i found that all my folders in storage folder where images are stored, have been deleted/removed. Should I again create those folders and try to create a symlink as I do in local project or there is some other procedure for doing that?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

The `public` directory in your project needs to be the public facing directory. From what you have described, you need to point `public_html` to your `public` directory. So you probably will have to deploy to another directory.

You will need to recreate your storage directories and files, as it sounds like they are being ignored. Check your .gitignore file to make sure the proper files and directories are being tracked.